# The app has been terminated. with error "Could not find an application at the specified directory"

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms

When I try to deploy my app on iOS device.app terminates with this error in the console.

> Error: error MT1001: Could not find an application at the specified directory: /Users/neelamprajapati/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs..

Although I have installed certificate and imported it.

Comment: Can you list your mtouch arguments from iOS project build properties?

Comment: mtouch arguments??? from where i can check that?

Comment: Right click on iOS project -> Properties -> iOS Build and there you have Additional mtouch arguments ;)

Comment: its blank......

Comment: Have you tried the solution in here: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=52757

Comment: Could you find any clue in the detail build log? https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/27515/how-to-obtain-diagnostic-build-logs

Comment: Did you solve this? I waste more than a day trying to debug in a device, I'm able to do it in VS Mac but this error only shows up in Windows

Comment: I also tried with a brand new project and it works fine, but the specific project I need to run does not work, I noticed if I go to the mac on that specific folder I see the folder with the name of the brand new project but not the project I'm having problems it's like VS does not even build there.

Answer (score 1):

Steps you can try:

1. Clean the project.
2. Delete bin and obj from folder if it's not properly cleaning.
3. Restart the VS.

Even though it can occur if you are having not valid proper certificate.

Comment: No luck on this

Answer (score 0):

If you have ReSharper extension, disable it. Go to Tools>Options>ReSharper Ultimate>Suspend now